# VB.net deserialize, JSON Conversion from type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' to type 'String'

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, web-services, serialization

So I have looked at many posts, but I am  still struggling with serializing this JSON object into classes. The JSON structure is this

`{"value":{"HashTag":"12342345636","companyname":"my test company","LeadDetail":{"id":"1","firstname":"john","lastname":"clark","email":"emak@mai.com","phone":"9874534444"}}}`

My class structure is as follows:

```
 <Serializable> _
Public Class LeadDetailCall
    Public Property Hash() As String
        Get
            Return m_Hash
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Hash = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Hash As String = ""
    Public Property CompanyName() As String
        Get
            Return _CompanyName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _CompanyName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _CompanyName As String = ""

    Public Property Details() As List(Of LeadDetail)
        Get
            Return _Details
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of LeadDetail))
            _Details = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Details As List(Of LeadDetail)
End Class
<Serializable> _
Public Class LeadDetail
    Private _id As String = ""
    Private _firstname As String = ""
    Private _lastname As String = ""
    Private _email As String = ""
    Private _phone As String = ""
    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property firstname() As String
        Get
            Return _firstname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _firstname = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property lastname() As String
        Get
            Return _lastname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _lastname = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property email() As String
        Get
            Return _email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _email = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property phone() As String
        Get
            Return _phone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _phone = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I call like so:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Function SendLeadDetails(ByVal value As Object) As UpdateResponse
    Dim CurCall As LeadDetailCall = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeadDetailCall)(value)
End Function
```

What have I tried? Using the JavaScriptSerializer, using http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/ crawling stackoverflow for examples. So many things that at this point I am flustered. So I continuously get the following invalid cast exception error.

```
 Conversion from type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' to type 'String' is not valid.
```

If anyone can help me out I would be very appreciative :)

Comment: Your classes imply that you expect or want to allow for a collection in the JSON, but thats not how it is constructed.  If so, can you post a sample with more than one entry (or a link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON provided only has one element, so it will result in a collection (dictionary) of one.  I added an "item" to be sure the code below worked and for illustration purposes.  Proper indentation makes things easier to follow:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "HashTag": "12342345636",
        "companyname": "my test company",
        "LeadDetail": {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "ziggy",
            "lastname": "clark",
            "email": "emak@mai.com",
            "phone": "9874534444"
        }
    },
    "bar": {
        "HashTag": "02342345636",
        "companyname": "my test company2",
        "LeadDetail": {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "john",
            "lastname": "clark",
            "email": "emak@mai.com",
            "phone": "1874534444"
        }
    }
}
```

Starting with the most deeply indented, it is easy to see a `LeadDetail` class with {ID, FirstName, etc).  With more than one item (as in mine), this would repeat.

Then there are "foo" and "bar" objects with a little data and a `LeadDetail` object.  When you use any of the Robots, they will create a class for each.  Mine would be named "foo" and "bar" but otherwise be identical.  In the code below, I condensed this to one class named "Item".  Then you can treat them (Foo and Bar) as a `Dictionary(of String, Item)` where their names are the keys.

But there is one more, less obvious class/Type:  The outer most `{..}`.  The robot tools will create a class named "Example" or "RootObject".  You dont need it or want it for a dictionary:

```
' modified from VS's EDIT -> Paste Special -> JSON as Classes
Public Class Item           
    Public Property HashTag As String
    Public Property companyname As String
    Public Property LeadDetail As Leaddetail
End Class

Public Class Leaddetail
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property firstname As String
    Public Property lastname As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property phone As String
End Class
```

Then the code:

```
Dim jstr As String = ...
' use the Item/Value class not the container
Dim myJ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Item))(jstr)

' print some of the data
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In myJ
    Console.WriteLine("key {0}, CompName {1}, Contact: {2}", kvp.Key,
                      kvp.Value.companyname,
                      kvp.Value.LeadDetail.firstname)
Next
```

Output:

> key: foo, CompName: my test company, Contact: ziggy
>   key: bar, CompName: my test company2, Contact: john

If you run it on your original JSON, you get a dictionary of one.

Comment: Awesomeness :) cause I actually understand that exception error now

Comment: Sometimes when you are lost in the forest it is hard to see the trees ;)

Comment: @Plutonix: Facing a same issue in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853014/getting-values-of-a-json-object-in-vb-net) but unable to sort it out. Can you please take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes don't seem to correspond properly to your Json.

Using http://jsonutils.com/, it suggested that your classes should look like this:

```
Public Class LeadDetail
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property firstname As String
    Public Property lastname As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property phone As String
End Class

Public Class Value
    Public Property HashTag As String
    Public Property companyname As String
    Public Property LeadDetail As LeadDetail
End Class

Public Class LeadDetailCall
    Public Property value As Value
End Class
```

Comment: Still getting the invalid cast exception though,

Comment: @kcbeard Don't know then. I'd suggest that instead of starting with the nested Json you have above, start with something very basic, like `{"value":"test"}` and see if you can get that to work, and if so, make the json a bit more complicated one thing at a time.

Comment: I had to serialize it to a string then deserialize the string to my object to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

@Keith Beard said before in this question that need to serialize and after that deserialize in to the classes. I was calling from ajax jquery to the webmethod.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function InsertObject (data As Object) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
        Dim _invoice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DtoInvoice)(jstr)

        'Make another stuff here

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```