# Getting Values of a JSON Object in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, webmethod

**EDITED:**

I got stuck while getting value of a JSON object in vb.net. My JSON request posts data like given below:

```
function submitEmail() {

        var ClientsPersonalInfo = {
            FullName: $("#FullName").val(),
            PhoneNumber: $("#PhoneNumber").val(),
            EmailAddress: $("#EmailAddress").val(),
            DOB: $("#DOB").val(),
            Occupation: $("#Occupation").val(),
            NINumber: $("#NINumber").val(),
            FullAddress: $("#FullAddress").val()
        }

        var ClientsData = {};
        ClientsData.ClientsPersonalInfo = ClientsPersonalInfo;

        var d = '{"ClientsData":' + JSON.stringify(ClientsData) + '}'

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add-new-client.aspx/SubmitEmail",
            data: d,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response)
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
}
```

**JSON Object Looks Like**

```
{
"ClientsPersonalInfo": {
    "FullName": "",
    "PhoneNumber": "",
    "EmailAddress": "",
    "DOB": "",
    "Occupation": "",
    "NINumber": "",
    "FullAddress": ""
    }
}
```

The above request returns an object in vb.net

VB Code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SubmitEmail(ByVal ClientsPersonalInfo As Object) As String

        // What to do next to get object "ClientsPersonalInfo"
        // I want to access properties of the object like
        //Dim name As String = ClientsPersonalInfo.FullName

        Return "Successfully Converted."

    End Function
```

No I want to get values of this object and needs to append in a table. Please guide me how to get values of the above object?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Question edited and added details.

Comment: I am a little confused with the edits.  Are you wanting a Dictionary of Clients (the json shown is more for 1 item) or a dictionary of client properties (that is rather than a Client Class, each property is a key)

Comment: @Plutonix I have edited the question that originally I did. I don't know how to get object's value in vb.net

Comment: dont you want to return the deserialized object rather than a string?

Comment: I need to get access properties of this object and needs to append in a table to send mail.

Comment: So what will be the best way to achieve it. I am a new in vb.net

Comment: is the vehicle info part of the deal or not?  It has come and gone while I have been typing an answer.  Radical edits like that are frowned on because it makes answers such as the one already posted look incorrect

Comment: Yes it is the part of it

Comment: Sorry for multiple edits but my json objects have multiple keys like `ClientPersonalInfo`, `ClientsVehicleInfo` and more

Comment: but it is *very hard* to hit a moving target.  The Dictionary aspect has disappeared from the question

Comment: Sorry guys. I need to close this question. I have started [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857007/getting-values-of-a-json-object-using-webmeothd-in-vb-net) with less and clean code. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem is not using `Option Strict On`.  The code at fault:

```
Shared Function SubmitEmail(ByVal ClientData As Object) As String
    Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of NewClientData)(ClientData)
```

If you turn on `Option Strict` that will not compile because `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` takes a string argument.  I am not sure why the exception (image now removed) seems to come from VB rather than Newtonsoft, but that isnt helping.

Your deserialized object will also just disappear when it goes out of scope when the method ends.

---

**Applicable to Edit #9**

The error mentioning a Dictionary seems misleading and probably something internal relating to how the properties are collected (many times json can be deserialized to a Dictionary(Of String, String).  Given the json posted (with data):

```
{
"ClientsData": {
    "ClientsPersonalInfo": {
        "FullName": "Ziggy Le Strange",
        "PhoneNumber": "505050",
        "EmailAddress": "ziggy@foobar.com",
        "DOB": "",
        "Occupation": "Freelancer",
        "NINumber": "7",
        "FullAddress": "123 Easy street"
    }
  }
}
```

There are actually 3 classes: `ClientsPersonalInfo` with the data, `ClientsData` which is a class containing that one and in previous edits also included a `ClientsVehicleInfo` class.

But there is yet another class represented by the enclosing `{...}`.  The robots who can create the classes for you name it `Example` or `RootObject`.  In this case, I would call it `ClientContainer`.

This works:

```
' the outermost {}
Public Class ClientContainer
    Public Property ClientsData As ClientsData
End Class

Public Class ClientsPersonalInfo
    Public Property FullName As String
    Public Property PhoneNumber As String
    Public Property EmailAddress As String
    Public Property DOB As String
    Public Property Occupation As String
    Public Property NINumber As String
    Public Property FullAddress As String
End Class

Public Class ClientsData
    Public Property ClientsPersonalInfo As ClientsPersonalInfo 
    Public Property ClientsVehicleInfo As ClientsVehicleInfo
End Class

Public Class ClientsVehicleInfo
    ' whatever it is supposed to hold
End Class
```

To deserialize the data (you may have to adapt it for web use, `Shared` seems incorrect to me):

```
' pass in the json AS STRING
' returns JUST the ClientsPersonalInfo
Public Function GetClientData(jsonData As String) As ClientsPersonalInfo

   ' you must use the container class 
    Dim client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ClientContainer)(jsonData )

    ' TEST:
    Console.WriteLine(client.ClientsData.ClientsPersonalInfo.FullName)

    Return client.ClientsData.ClientsPersonalInfo

End Function
```

`ClientsData` seems to be an unneeded layer.  The container could hold both of the other objects directly.   *If* this is meant to hold info for more than one client, you would have keys in place of `"ClientsData":` in the json (e.g. `"ziggy":{}, "zacky":{}, "zoey":{}`.

Output:

> Ziggy Le Strange

Since, as per comment, that vehicle info is part of the deal, you can change it to return `ClientsData` which holds both the Personal and Vehicle info:

```
Public Function GetClientData(jsonData As String) As ClientsData

   ' you must use the container class 
    Dim client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ClientContainer)(jsonData )

    Return client.ClientsData
```

1. Turn on `Option Strict`
2. Dont box parameters or returns `As Object`, they loose some of their meaning.
3. Keep in mind that the outermost braces in json represent a container object

Also, storing a Date as string looks bad too.

Comment: There were some errors in my original post because I could not keep up with your edits.  Your ClientData class is incorrect  `Public Property ClientsPersonalInfo As ClientsPersonalInfo`

Comment: Get rid of above error but now this error: http://imageshack.com/a/img911/4020/G8MpZy.jpg

Comment: It probably needs that `<WebMethod()>` attribute (at least).  I know nothing about web coding which is why I did not read/answer this post until you asked.  The code works  - you can paste it into a WinForms app and use `Dim jsonData = File.ReadAllText(THe_JSON_FILENAME)` to load sample json to test it.  *How* to implement it is beyond my expertise

Comment: Ok no problem. By the way thanks for you help buddy.

Comment: you could try changing the name and adding `Shared`.  that seems to be the only real difference in the setup (GetClientData could conflict with something relating to the web client - I dont know).

Answer (score 2):

1. First make sure your Json is in valid format using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)
2. Then generate class base on it using [jsonutils](http://jsonutils.com/)

   ```
   Public Class ClientsPersonalInfo
      Public Property FullName As String
      Public Property PhoneNumber As String
      Public Property EmailAddress As String
      Public Property DOB As String
      Public Property Occupation As String
      Public Property NINumber As String
      Public Property FullAddress As String
   End Class

   Public Class ClientsVehicleInfo
      Public Property DrivingLicense As String
      Public Property VehicleMakeModel As String
      Public Property VehicleColour As String
      Public Property PolicyNumber As String
      Public Property TypeOfCover As String
      Public Property VehicleStoredIn As String
   End Class

   Public Class ClientsData
      Public Property ClientsPersonalInfo As ClientsPersonalInfo
      Public Property ClientsVehicleInfo As ClientsVehicleInfo
   End Class

   Public Class ClientData
      Public Property ClientsData As ClientsData
   End Class
   ```
3. Use [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) to deserialize your Json into object(s) then you may simply access its properties value. (remember to add Json.net to your project using Manage NuGet Packages)

   ```
   Imports Newtonsoft.Json

   Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, ClientsData))(yourJsonString)
   ```

Comment: I did till second step but i don't know what to use generated class

Comment: I have added json object in question

Comment: After doing this getting this error: Conversion from type 'Dictionary(Of String,Object)' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: I have added json object in question

Comment: i have edited question and added vb and javascript code

Comment: what will be yourJsonString?

Comment: ClientsData is my json object passed as a prameter in SubmitEmail function